# Passing coredata from tableview to another tableview

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitableview

I am struggling with getting my care data to populate my second tableview controller. The data is populating the first tableview and I can select a row and the segue is used to go to the second table but the labels are not populated.

I've looked all over and have found older samples or obj-c but I cannot figure it out, so any help pointing this n00b in the right direction will be helpful.

Here is what I have, I think I am missing how to populate a variable to pass in `prepareForSegue` in the list tableview, but I could be wrong. I get a warning error in that function (`Warning cannot assign value of type 'ListEntity' to type '[ListEntity]'`).

**CoreData**

```
Entity = ListEntity
Attributes = title, event & location (all as Strings)
```

**listTableViewController**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var lists = [ListEntity]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "The List"

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: #selector(ListTableViewController.addButtonMethod))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

    }

    func addButtonMethod() {
        print("Perform action")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        reloadData()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func reloadData() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ListEntity")
        do {
            if let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [ListEntity] {
                lists = results
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("There was an error fetching the list!")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lists.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell") as! ListTableViewCell
        let list = lists[indexPath.row]
        cell.configurationWithSetup(list)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailsSegue", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

     }

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

         if segue.identifier == "DetailsSegue" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsTableViewController
            let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            print(indexPath.row) // Print the Row selected to console
            // Place the code to pass data here?
            // destinationVC.lists = lists[indexPath.row]
            // Warning cannot assign value of type 'ListEntity' to type '[ListEntity]'
          }
    }
}
```

**listTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    func configurationWithSetup(list: AnyObject) {
        titleLabel.text = list.valueForKey("title") as! String?
    }
}
```

**detailsTableViewController**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var lists = [ListEntity]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DataCell") as! DetailsTableViewCell
        let list = lists[indexPath.row]
        cell.configurationWithSetup(list)

        return cell
    }
}
```

**detailsTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!

    func configurationWithSetup(list: AnyObject) {

        titleLabel.text = list.valueForKey("title") as! String?
        eventLabel.text = list.valueForKey("event") as! String?
        locationLabel.text = list.valueForKey("location") as! String?

    }
}
```

Comment: i think u must just add the whole lists // destinationVC.lists = lists and not just lists[indexPath.row]

Comment: @UlliH thanks for the tip. I did change the code to reflect that, I also noticed that the detailsTableViewController had the DataCell class set to `listTableViewCell` and identifier to `ListCell` since I copied and pasted it. I changed the class to `detailsTableViewCell` and the identifier to `DataCell` as in storyboard and now I get fields populated in the detailsTableViewController.

Comment: BUT - Now I am only getting the first cell's data in all the rows so if I click row 1 i get the right data. If I click row 2,3,4,etc. I sill get only row 1 data in the detail view controller.

Comment: The warning contains the answer - just change var lists = [ListEntity]() to var lists = ListEntity(), or var lists:ListEntity! and when you prepare for segue set that value.

Comment: The warning is extremely clear. You are trying to assign the wrong type to `var lists` in `detailsTableViewController`. `lists[indexPath.row]` returns the type `ListEntity`. If this is what you want to pass then the `var lists` line in `detailsTableViewController` should accept a `ListEntity` type NOT an array of `ListEntity`. Of course, then the line `let list = lists[indexPath.row]` should be deleted and the next line should be `cell.configurationWithSetup(lists)`. By the way, your use of `AnyObject` is poor coding - use the correct type instead.

Comment: @RoboticCat thanks for your comment. I'm trying to understand that I can remove the brackets to not make it an array. But was following  code that I thought would work. so I tried what you suggested and now the app crashes. I'm new to this so if you can tell me what you mean about `AnyObject` I'd appreciate it.

Comment: i see, u are helped meanwhile :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning contains the answer - just change

`var lists = [ListEntity]()` to 
`var lists = ListEntity()`, or `var lists:ListEntity!` and when you prepare for segue set that value.

Then you will need to change

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DataCell") as! DetailsTableViewCell
        // as data source is not array you can just you the item you passed
        // let list = lists[indexPath.row]
        cell.configurationWithSetup(lists)

        return cell
    }
```

You should use a static table view if you just want one cell

More info per you current issue

```
class DetailsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

   var theDetailListEntity:ListEntity! 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(theDetailListEntity) // check that you passed it across
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DataCell") as! DetailsTableViewCell
        cell.configurationWithSetup(theDetailListEntity)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add prepare for segue in the `listTableViewController` otherwise `theDetailListEntity` won't be set... and then it will crash.

Depending on how you set up your segue, it may differ. But this is what you need

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showMyDetailView", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showMyDetailView" {
        guard let
            vc = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsTableViewController,
            ip = sender as? NSIndexPath else { fatalError() }
        let item = lists[ip.row]
        vc.theDetailListEntity = item
        // set the item in the next VC
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(ip, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I only do this on the `DetailsTableViewController`? I also changed `DetailsTableViewCell` with `func configurationWithSetup(lists: AnyObject) {
        titleLabel.text = lists.valueForKey("title") as! String?` and now the app crashes when I click on the row in the initial table view.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<passingData.ListEntity 0x7fcf394434b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "title".'

Comment: In the master view are you passing the data to the detail view ? In viewDidLoad of the detail view do a simple print and check if it has been passed across.

Comment: I have edited the code as you suggested and it seems to work, thanks. But now to help me understand it a bit more. In the `DetailsTableViewController` you are creating a variable `var theDetailListEntity:ListEntity!` what does the colon do? you are assigning `theDetailListEntity` as the `ListEntity`? Why change the name?

Comment: Colon is setting the type of the Var that you will set it to, as you don't have the object until you pass it to the view controller via a segue. I changed the name to try and help you understand what is happening.

Comment: So is it best practice to change the entity name in the new controller or to keep it the same though the lifecycle of the app?

Comment: You had lists which implies an array, i'd called it listItem or item or whatever you like, but the prior VC was lists and it was an array, so the detail view shouldn't be called lists as well as its a single element from that array.